# NodeJS Geometry string from GPS coordinates before sending to DB?

Tags: postgis, coordinate-system, node-js

I'm building an application that saves geographical data to the postgresql db with postgis extension.

The data I'm saving is in EPSG 4326 WGS84 format, so I'm sending lat/lng coordinates to the postgresql and on insert, it changes the coordinates to a geometry **POINT** string like so:

```
GPS (39.10, 9.10)
POINT (1000FF111FFFGGGAAA1) // casual digits and letters
```

Before sending the data to the db I need to transform the point from **EPSG 4326 to 32632** so that I can apply geometric functions to the geometric points. I know how to use ST_Transform, and the translation happens on the DB. What I would like to do is to make the transformation happen on the server so that the point is inserted directly with **32632 SRID**.

Is it possible?

Comment: not sure if I get that; you want to pre-transform your points within *node.js*? I wouldn't, PostGIS is really good at that, why adding another processing layer in-between? apart from that, having your data in EPSG:4326 has certain benefits, namely interchangeability and, most of all, the possible cast to `GEOGRAPHY` that let's you get highly precise calculations in a proper setting. it depends somewhat on the functionality you are aiming at; what do you have in mind here?

Comment: Hello ThingumaBob, thanks for helping me out! I managed to do it withing nodejs by using PRO4J package. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The coordinates SR can be changed within nodejs by using **PRO4J** ported package, by defining the SRs needed and their definitions, which can be found on geoportals.